# How can I disable animation in a reactjs component first time

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a list of items. I want each time I add or remove an item from the list to have animation. Everything it's OK with that.

My only problem is that I want to disable the animation first time when  the component initialize.

http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/6887/

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {items: []};
    },
    addColor:function(){
    this.setState({items:this.state.items.concat('new color')});
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var items = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];
        this.setState({items: items});
    },
    render: function () {
        var contentList = this.state.items.map(function (i,k) {
            return (<li>{i}</li>);
        });
        return (
                <div>
                Hello <button onClick={this.addColor}>add</button>
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
                {contentList}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

                </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.body);
```

So, how can I make the animation appear only when changing the list and not ont the very first setState from didMount    method?

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Are you using the React animation addon?

Comment: Added some example code.

Comment: In your example, you could move the state into `getInitialState`. However, if your real code must fetch the data in `DidMount`, you could use a dynamic `transitionName` in `render`. Leave it undefined by default, and set another value like `firstFetchComplete` that's set when the data is ready. If `firstFetchComplete` is true, set `transitionName` to its real value.

Answer (score 2):

Using `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount` it will work perfectly as shown in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ghislaindj/jpuyd3gb/1/

However, if your real code must fetch the data in DidMount, you should use ssorallen comment.